# Replacing the removed database diagrams feature

Tags: ssms, database-diagrams

I have a SQL Server database and want to create an ER diagram for it, to analyze tables and relationships.

The option to create a diagram is no longer present in SSMS 18.

Is there any free tool that would help me to create such a diagram, or another workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update to the [latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) of SSMS. The database diagrams feature was [reinstated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms#whats-new-in-181) starting with version 18.1.